# How to have a Customized Spring batch Job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a question. I want to have a 'parent' job that extends  SimpleJob and does some additional things that is common to a group of child jobs. It also registers a listener. What I want is something of the following sort.

```
      class parentJob extends SimpleJob{
       ......}
```

And then in the spring-config file:

```
      <job id="parentJob" class="classname" abstract="true">
            <listeners>
               <listener ref="parentListener"/>
            </listeners>
      </job>

      <job id="childJob1" parent="parentJob">
            <listeners merge="true">
               <listener ref="childListener"/>
            </listeners>
      </job>
```

But looks like we cannot define a "parentJob" with the "job" tag and a 'class' property. Then how does one extend the Job interface in Spring Batch?

Could someone please guide me on what I want to achieve? Is there an example of someone extending the SimpleJob class? Also, does a child class that extends the SimpleJob allow registering Listeners the same way? I mean something of the sort:

```
       <job id="customJob" class="classThatExtendsSimpleJob">
            <listeners>
               <listener ref="someListener" />
             </listeners>
       </job>
```

Thanks as always

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a custom builder factory for your job (or step) and add the default functionality by calling the appropriate methods on the builder.

see [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-4-job-inheritance/).

Comment: Thanks, @Raul. That doesn't answer how should the spring configuration be done to achieve what I want.